How to Implement Privacy-Preserving Ether Transactions on Ethereum?
I'm researching how to send Ether in a private and secure manner, similar to Monero's stealth addresses and ring signatures. My goal is to hide the recipient's address and transaction details from public visibility, ensuring strong privacy for both the sender and receiver.For example, I want to create a reward system that anonymously sends rewards to people after they submit information, ensuring their identity privacy!
So far, I'm considering the following techniques:
Stealth addresses: Is there a way to generate one-time addresses on Ethereum for the recipient, as Monero does, to hide their identity?
Ring signatures: Could a similar concept be applied on Ethereum to mask the sender's identity within a group of potential senders?
Confidential transactions: I've heard zk-SNARKs could be useful for hiding transaction amounts. How can zk-SNARKs or other privacy protocols like Aztec be integrated to make the transaction details confidential?
Are there existing tools, libraries, or smart contracts on Ethereum that can facilitate these privacy features? What would be the recommended approach to build a system like this on the Ethereum platform?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
If this idea has no practical value, please let me know and I will promptly change my approach!
